# Logging exception without changing existing code

Tags: asp.net

I have a application, and I want to log exceptions to a file and I don't want to change any code.  I just want a component to which I can add my code and it will start logging exceptions.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET you can create a custom `IHttpModule` implementation and in it's `Init` method register an event handler for `HttpApplication.Error`.  Log exceptions as needed when the error event is triggered.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class ErrorLoggingModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.Error += OnError;
        }

        private static void OnError(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();

            // log exception here...
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) (Error Logging Modules and Handlers)

> is an application-wide error logging
>   facility that is completely pluggable.
>   It can be dynamically added to a
>   running ASP.NET  web application, or
>   even all ASP.NET web applications on a
>   machine, without any need for
>   re-compilation or re-deployment.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET [Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx) is pretty useful, you just need to configure it in web.config.